# Having issue with back reference in TCL

Tags: regex, tcl, regexp-replace, regexp-substr

I have the following code:

```
set a "10.20.30.40"
regsub -all {.([0-9]+).([0-9]+).} $a {\2 \1} b
```

I am trying to grep 2nd and 3rd octet of the IP address.

Expected output:

```
20 30
```

Actual output:

```
20 04 0
```

What is my mistake here?

Comment: You need to escape "." character like "\." . Without escaping, "." matches any character.

Comment: tried the same , but no luck regsub -all {\.([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.} $a {\2 \1} b

Comment: @Bharathi : Sorry. Your intention is not clear to me. Do you need to match the `20.30.` in the variable `a` and replace it with some other ?

Comment: Got it. You need replace ".20.30" with "30.20". Right ?

Comment: @Bharathi : If you simply want to save the 2nd and 3rd octet, then why `regsub` at all ? `regexp` itself is enough, Right ? Why bother back-reference also ?

Comment: This is one of the situations where regex is not a suitable tool. You should `split` instead of trying to do that... `[split $a .]` gives you `{10 20 30 40}` which you can easily then use `lrange` to get the second and third elements together...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the variables for the match and captured groups, then you can access them. Here is an example:

```
set a "10.20.30.40"
set rest [regexp {[0-9]+\.([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.[0-9]+} $a match submatch1 submatch2]
puts $submatch1
puts $submatch2
```

Output of [the demo](https://ideone.com/ekWz8Z)

```
20
30
```

**EDIT**:

You can use regsub and backerferences this way (I am now replacing the 3rd and 2nd octets, just for demonstration). Note that a literal dot must be escaped:

```
set a "10.20.30.40"
regsub -all {\.([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.} $a {.\2.\1.} b
puts $b
```

Output of the [demo](https://ideone.com/dP1pKo):

```
10.30.20.40
```

To obtain a "20 30" string, you need to use

```
regsub -all {^[0-9]+\.([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.[0-9]+$} $a {\1 \2} b
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but i want to grep those octets using regsub and back reference. ... as mentioned in my question , regesub command is available . but it is not working

Comment: Thanks :) .... it is working fine.. Could you please let me know any docs to understand  about back reference

Comment: Sure, the best IMO is [Regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html).

Comment: i have one more question , could you please help me out.  set a "1 abc 2 abc 3 abc 4 abc 5 abc 6 abc 7 abcd" . i want replace first 3 "abc" as bhu usinf regsub and back reference ... please help me on this..

Comment: Here you are: `set a "1 abc 2 abc 3 abc 4 abc 5 abc 6 abc 7 abcd" \\NEWLINE
regsub {([0-9]+\s+)abc( +[0-9]+ +)abc( +[0-9]+ +)abc(.*)} $a {\1bhu\2bhu\3bhu\4} b \\NEWLINE
puts $b`. Instead of `\\NEWLINE`, use a real newline.

Comment: Hi thanks, here whether can we use bound quantifiers or anything for following scenrio, because consider variable a have "1 abc 2 abc ......100 abc"  in that i want to match first 50 abc matches.... then our regsub will be very lengthy..... we need to avoid this .... any idea ???

Answer (score 2):

I'd stay away from regular expressions altogether:

```
set b [join [lrange [split $a .] 1 2]]
```

Split the value on dots, take the 2nd and 3nd elements, and join them with a space.